# Voice Over Record doesn't record, displays "Finishing" then stops

Tags: premiere, audio, audio-recording

I've been consistently getting this behavior, it's not clear to me what is causing it.  If I switch to another clip, often I am able to record.

I am using an external ASIO recording interface to do the recording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've figured it out.  I've been setting my in point to the start of the clip and my end point to the end of the clip.  By moving the start in point after the first bit of footage, it records just fine.